# Prompt Flow LLM Node Not Allowing Association to Connection

Tags: azure-promptflow

I am looking to create a PromptFlow with the Llama LLM model.  I was able to successfully deploy Llama and establish my connection as shown in the picture below.  However when I add a new LLM Node to my Prompt Flow my connections list appears as empty.

Any insight on what I need to do to ensure my Llama connect appears as an option in the LLM node?

[image: VS Code Prompt Flow with No Ability to Add Llama Connection]